# Is it possible to add a foreign key via annotations without adding an association in Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using DDD and don't want to create an association that's not needed in Doctrine between aggregates. Additionally the "foreign key" is a primary key, and not the actual entity being referenced.

Is there a way to create the foreign key relationship in the database using annotations of the foreign key field, without creating the association in the application Doctrine layer (using One-to-Many, One-to-One, etc).

Comment: Do you mean you've got entities in the [Class Table Inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) pattern? Could then simply define the root aggregate as having these properties and the other Entity classes extend from that. Doctrine takes care of the `DiscriminatorMap` declaration, so you need only `InheritanceType`, and `DiscriminatorColumn` on the root aggregate. Doctrine then also creates your foreign keys (PK id of root aggregate)

Answer (score 0):

You can import mapping:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

like this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" yml --path=config/doctrine
```

remove the relationship from the generated yml files and generate entities after:

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App
```